# TypeError: get_stream_position() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, typeerror, arcade

I have googled a bunch on how to fix this problem, but I'm kind of a beginner and none of the articles were related to python arcade, so I couldn't figure it out.

I'm trying to play background music in my game and I tried the **python arcade** [**Background Music example**](https://arcade.academy/examples/background_music.html#background-music), but upon trying to get the position the example throws an error at me, saying: `TypeError: get_stream_position() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Has some update messed up some code or something?

> *Heres the code I think is relevant to the problem:*

```
def __init__(self, width, height, title):
    super().__init__(width, height, title)

    arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)

    self.music_list = []
    self.current_song_index = 0
    self.current_player = None
    self.music = None

def advance_song(self):

    self.current_song_index += 1
    if self.current_song_index >= len(self.music_list):
        self.current_song_index = 0
    print(f"Advancing song to {self.current_song_index}.")

def play_song(self):

    if self.music:
        self.music.stop()

    print(f"Playing {self.music_list[self.current_song_index]}")
    self.music = arcade.Sound(self.music_list[self.current_song_index], streaming=True)
    self.current_player = self.music.play(MUSIC_VOLUME)
    time.sleep(0.03)

def setup(self):

    self.music_list = [":resources:music/funkyrobot.mp3", ":resources:music/1918.mp3"]
    self.current_song_index = 0
    self.play_song()

def on_update(self, dt):

    position = self.music.get_stream_position(self.current_player)

    if position == 0.0:
        self.advance_song()
        self.play_song()
```

> *Here's the full error:*

```
Playing :resources:music/funkyrobot.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/[name]/Documents/Projects/background_music.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/[name]/Documents/Projects/background_music.py", line 74, in main
    arcade.run()
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\arcade\window_commands.py", line 236, in run
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 107, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 167, in run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 237, in idle
    redraw_all = self.clock.call_scheduled_functions(dt)
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\clock.py", line 292, in call_scheduled_functions
    item.func(now - item.last_ts, *item.args, **item.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 213, in _dispatch_updates
    self.dispatch_event('on_update', delta_time)
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1333, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 422, in dispatch_event
    self._raise_dispatch_exception(event_type, args, getattr(self, event_type), exception)
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 476, in _raise_dispatch_exception
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 415, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "c:/Users/[name]/Documents/Projects/background_music.py", line 65, in on_update
    position = self.music.get_stream_position(self.current_player)
TypeError: get_stream_position() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**TL;DR**: [Example](https://arcade.academy/examples/background_music.html#background-music) I wanted to use as reference doesn't function - `TypeError: get_stream_position() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that you're using old Arcade version. You have two options:

- update Arcade with `pip install arcade --upgrade`
- slightly modify your code by removing all arguments from  `self.music.get_stream_position()`

Here is the working example for old Arcade version:

```
import arcade
import time

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300
SCREEN_TITLE = "Starting Template Simple"
MUSIC_VOLUME = 0.5


class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """ Main application class. """

    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)

        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)

        # Variables used to manage our music. See setup() for giving them
        # values.
        self.music_list = []
        self.current_song_index = 0
        self.current_player = None
        self.music = None

    def advance_song(self):
        """ Advance our pointer to the next song. This does NOT start the song. """
        self.current_song_index += 1
        if self.current_song_index >= len(self.music_list):
            self.current_song_index = 0
        print(f"Advancing song to {self.current_song_index}.")

    def play_song(self):
        """ Play the song. """
        # Stop what is currently playing.
        if self.music:
            self.music.stop()

        # Play the next song
        print(f"Playing {self.music_list[self.current_song_index]}")
        self.music = arcade.Sound(self.music_list[self.current_song_index], streaming=True)
        self.current_player = self.music.play(MUSIC_VOLUME)
        # This is a quick delay. If we don't do this, our elapsed time is 0.0
        # and on_update will think the music is over and advance us to the next
        # song before starting this one.
        time.sleep(0.03)

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game here. Call this function to restart the game. """

        # List of music
        self.music_list = [":resources:music/funkyrobot.mp3", ":resources:music/1918.mp3"]
        # Array index of what to play
        self.current_song_index = 0
        # Play the song
        self.play_song()

    def on_draw(self):
        """ Render the screen. """

        arcade.start_render()

        position = self.music.get_stream_position()
        length = self.music.get_length()

        size = 20
        margin = size * .5

        # Print time elapsed and total
        y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - (size + margin)
        text = f"{int(position) // 60}:{int(position) % 60:02} of {int(length) // 60}:{int(length) % 60:02}"
        arcade.draw_text(text, 0, y, arcade.csscolor.BLACK, size)

        # Print current song
        y -= size + margin
        text = f"Currently playing: {self.music_list[self.current_song_index]}"
        arcade.draw_text(text, 0, y, arcade.csscolor.BLACK, size)

    def on_update(self, dt):

        position = self.music.get_stream_position()

        # The position pointer is reset to 0 right after we finish the song.
        # This makes it very difficult to figure out if we just started playing
        # or if we are doing playing.
        if position == 0.0:
            self.advance_song()
            self.play_song()


def main():
    """ Main method """
    window = MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```